Transcribing text on Death Record

I am interested with the second entry. I know the date is November 1st 1931. And I know he died in Murrayville, Victoria, Australia.
But I am trying to make out the rest. I know it mentions county.

Shire Walpeup
County of Weeah
Here's how I figured it out:
Went to:
https://trove.nla.gov.au/
Searched for:
Murrayville Shire
(saw Walpeup mentioned a few times)
Did another search on Walpeup County
and saw:
County of Weeah in the first few results
I don't have any connection to this area but happy to help with my search engine-fu!

Awesome. None of the words seemed familiar to me. Searching the transcription you provided resulted with: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shire_of_Walpeup

I came to the same conclusion by searching on "murrayville shire" to find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rural_City_of_Mildura which gave me the shire name and then on "shire walpeup county" to find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shire_of_Walpeup

I had had a lot of success doing one of two things.  Either asking an AI tool such as ChatGPT to transcribe the image for me.  Or, posting the image in "Deciphering Genealogy Script" at https://www.facebook.com/groups/672462506205064
Chat GPT says the circled info is:
November 1st
1931
Murrayville
Shire Walpunga
County Wicca
MR Murrayville

DV because the answer is not useful. Not only is there already an accepted answer that is correct, but also this answer is incorrect.
